# What is the best way to create a database diagram for SQL Azure without having to install SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-diagrams

I have a database on SQL Azure and want to create a database diagram for that, but don't want to have to install SQL server and copy the database etc.  Is there any way that I can do it that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**: [The database diagrams were added back into SSMS 18.1(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

**UPDATE**: the database diagram feature

> **Deprecated and removed features in 18.0 (GA)**
>   ...
>   Database Diagrams
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms

The feature was also removed from Visual Studio 2019 SSDT.

**Original Answer**

The latest version of SSMS (as of v16) supports creating database diagrams for Azure SQL databases. You can download it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: +1, as does v17.x Tends to be quite slow when adding a large number of tables to a diagram, though.

Comment: _Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15517)_

Comment: The database diagrams were added back into SSMS 18.1

Comment: I still get same error in 18.1

Answer (score 4):

SQL Azure databases do not support diagrams in the same way 'normal' on premise SQL Servers do, so you are looking at workarounds or third-party tools.  For example, you could install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), pull your model down, deploy to a local 'normal' dev server, create the diagram there.  This would not involve much data so would be lightweight.  Alternately use Viso, Powerpoint, dbForge, Erwin, RedGate, Apex ... paper and pencil etc : )

A little additional research shows Red Gate have recently added more support for SQL Azure and have a free trial, and [SQL Power Doc](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/) which looks useful and could plug into [NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/) for example.

In summary, the tooling hasn't quite caught up but  you have a few options.